# YouTube API search.list -> JSON data; How to use "id/snippet" to populate iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube, youtube-api

Here is my code:

```
//iframe
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    player = new YT.Player('player',{
        height: '240',
        width: '320',
        videoId: "<--!XXXXXXX-->",
        events : {
            'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    console.log('ytiframe api is rdy');
}
function onPlayerReady(e){
    e.target.playVideo();
    console.log('ytplayer is rdy');
}

function onPlayerStateChange () {
    console.log('ytplayer state changed');
}


//search
function showResponse(response) {
    var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = responseString;
}
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('YT API KET');
    search();
}
function search() {
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'id',
        q: 'video',
        maxResults:1,
        order: 'date'
    });
    setTimeout(search, 5000);
    console.log('Search success');
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}
```

And an example of the JSON.stringify results:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/28PNG8cez--chz5e--vPEnvku1M\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
  "regionCode": "CA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/foAQ8JoA3_ECBS6pmAR96pU3mm0\"",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "tkui2fSqP2M"
      }
    }
  ],
  "result": {
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/28PNG8cez--chz5e--vPEnvku1M\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
    "regionCode": "CA",
    "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 1000000,
      "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
        "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/foAQ8JoA3_ECBS6pmAR96pU3mm0\"",
        "id": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "tkui2fSqP2M"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I simply want to take **"videoId": "6DJTgpOu7rs"** from this JSON and use it for the YT.Player. So, the `videoId: 'xxxxxx';` would be a variable instead.

I'm not sure if I need to parse, or how to structure it so I can access the JSON data.

I've searched around about this and maybe my terminology is off, but I haven't seen anything exactly like this. So, I digress if this has been answered before.

Comment: `jsonobject.result.items[0].id.videoId`

Comment: @SusheelSingh Thanks! I'm not quite sure I understand though. I'll expand:

Using a iFrame function like this:

`function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: "videoId",
  `

Could I put **"jsonobject.result.items[0].id.videoId"** in place of **"videoId"**?

Comment: yes but you need loop over the json object if there are multiple results

Comment: EDIT: I've updated the code to include what I am currently using for an iFrame creator and hopefully have made it more clear. @SusheelSingh with the phrasing/vars I have, what would be the steps to allow me to use `x.result.items[0].id.videoId` as a variable?

Comment: in which function you are getting the response

Comment: If i understand it correctly 
`function search() {
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'id',
        q: 'video',
        maxResults:1,
        order: 'date'
    });` communicates with https://apis.google.com/js/client.js and YT to receive info that is strigified by the `function showResponse(response) {
    var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = responseString;
}` function. @SusheelSingh

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as below:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(id){
    player = new YT.Player('player',{
        height: '240',
        width: '320',
        videoId: id,
        events : {
            'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    console.log('ytiframe api is rdy');
} 


function showResponse(response) {
   onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(response.result.items[0].id.videoId);
}
```

Comment: not sure if it is because of the order of the script or something, but this just doesn't work. I don't get any error messages, but maybe the JSON path is off or `(id)` should be `(videoId)` (tried that didn't do anything).

Comment: please console.log everything and debug what all you are getting